# Knowledge on strings

Tags: python, string

What does this code mean?

```
S[len(S)-1]
```

I'm learning strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please don't use ALL CAPS. It reads as though you're shouting at us. You probably don't mean to shout at people you're asking for help. You probably want to work through some basic Python tutorials as well.

Comment: Do you know what `[]` means? Do you know what `len` means? Do you know what `-1` means? What aspect of the code you have given are you unable to follow?

Answer (score 0):

This code is grabbing the last character of a string. I would recommend using Python's shell interface to test things like this out. If `S` is a string of arbitrary length, it is taking the length of the string. Indices are 0 indexed in python, so if you were to ask for `S[len(S)]` the index would be out of bounds. You subtract 1 from the length to get the final character.

Here's a few test cases so you can see the results:

```
>>> S="hello"
>>> S[len(S)-1]
'o'
>>> S = "Hello World!"
>>> S[len(S)-1]
'!'
>>> S = "Python is cool"
>>> S[len(S)-1]
'l'
```

I hope this helps.